# how to input default value into hidden input

Tags: php, html

I have this database with the following data:
        data 1: text1
        data 2: text2
        .
        .
        .
        data 14: text 14

I was trying to input this data into a "select" column. So I had done this:

```
<script>
function dropdownlistchange(dropDown) {
    var selectedValue = dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("category").value = selectedValue;
}
</script>
```

and the display is:

```
<?php
$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 
mysqli_select_db($con,"adminsys") or die ("no database");  
$query = "SELECT * FROM productmodelcategory";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query)or die("Connection could not be established");
echo "<select class='categoryoption' name='categorylist' id='categorylist' onChange='dropdownlistchange(this);'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
{
echo "<option value='".$row['Category']."'selected='selected'>".$row['Category']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

and my display output is:

```
<input name="category" type="hidden" id="category" value="" required="required"/>
```

The problem that I having is I am attaching this coding in a submit form, and when I try to not selecting any value due to leave it as default value, and when i submit form, the value displaying "Column 'Category' cannot be null". Anyone can help me solve this problem? I not sure changing the "onchange" method into what method.

Comment: either you have bad data in your database, or your Category colum doesn't exist and you should be whipped for not using error_reporting(E_ALL) during development... to find out which, use var_dump($row);   also, are you sure that Category is stored in your database already pre-html escaped? else, lookup htmlentities()

Comment: at the time of insertion check that value and if it is null then you can set default value there

Answer (score 0):

Your `category input` will hold some value when user actually select something from `dropdown`. If user didn't select anything in this case `category input` will not hold any value.

Do one thing assign `value` attribute to your `category input` like below

```
<input name="category" type="hidden" id="category" required="required" value="0"/>
```

Else, you can set 1st row value as default as follow

```
<?php
$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect to mysql"); 
mysqli_select_db($con,"adminsys") or die ("no database");  
$query = "SELECT * FROM productmodelcategory";
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query)or die("Connection could not be established");
echo "<select class='categoryoption' name='categorylist' id='categorylist' onChange='dropdownlistchange(this);'>";
$i = 0;
$default_value =0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    if($i == 0){
        $default_value = $row['Category'];
        $i = 1;
    }
    echo "<option value='".$row['Category']."'selected='selected'>".$row['Category']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
<input name="category" type="hidden" id="category" required="required" value="<?php echo $default_value;?>"/>
```